# Azure Devops Release Pipeline - How to avoid deploying particular tags to test servers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, cicd

I have release pipeline set. When I checkin code in repository I tag last commit in format x.xx.y where y= 0. After tagging build get trigger and after successful build, code get deploy on test environment.

When a bugs comes I create tag on bug commit like x.xx.z where z = 1-99. now here as well build get trigger and it get deploy to test environments however here I dont want bug fix should get deploy to test environment. So is there any sort of pattern that I can use to only deploy non bug commit to  test environment or any other differnt solution?

Right now I am using Build Branch as "refs/tags/*" in "Continuous deployment trigger" in release pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you can try to set the Stage **Artifact filters** (`Pre-deployment conditions ->Artifact filters`) to target tags.

For example: `x.xx.0`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin Lu-MSFT. 
I tried it however it did not work. Is there any possibility that we can put any kind of pattern when adding a branch to recognize certain tags only. Here x.xx.0 can be 1.1.0 or 2.3.0

Comment: @user2839740. I can understand your requirement. But based on my test, wildcards(*) cannot be loaded in the tag name. So the current method is hard cord the tag name.